# Unable to debug our Remote Event Receiver using Azure service bus. "One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. "

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver, service-bus

I am developing a remote event receiver for our site collection. so inside Visual Studio 2015, i did the following:-

1. i created a new sharepoint add-in of type provider hosted app. I added the code as per this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/.

For the debugging site collection i chose a test enterprise wiki online site collection which I have enabled its Sideloading of apps feature.

2. inside Azure i created a new service bus, as follow >> i copied the primary connection string:-
   [image]
3. inside the visual studio project >> Properties >> SharePoint >> i added the above service bus's primary connection string, as follow:-
   [image]
4. i run the project >> where i got this message >> i select the list >> click on "Trust":-
   [image]
5. i got the app home page as follow:-
   [image]
6. i got the app added correctly inside my site content:-
   [image]

but the visual studio stop running and showed these 2 messages:-
[image]

> One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure
>   Service Bus. Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on
>   Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server

**so i am not sure what is going on ? why the service bus is not working, and as a result we are not able to debug our remote event receiver?**

here is my AppManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="CustomerServiceKB"
     ProductID="{28e4281a-1114-4d41-82dd-6277e01c7d34}"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     SharePointMinVersion="16.0.0.0"
>
  <Properties>
    <Title>CustomerServiceKB</Title>
    <StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
    <InstalledEventEndpoint>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc</InstalledEventEndpoint>
    <UninstallingEventEndpoint>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc</UninstallingEventEndpoint>
  </Properties>

  <AppPrincipal>
    <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />
  </AppPrincipal>
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Manage" >
       <Property Name="BaseTemplateId" Value="100" />
    </AppPermissionRequest>
  </AppPermissionRequests>
</App>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your SharePoint App project in Visual Studio and select “SharePoint“. There you can uncheck “Enable Remote Event Debugging“. It no longer works with debugging provided hosted app. Instead attach a cloud debugger to the azure web app to debug.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. but you mentioned ` Instead attach a cloud debugger to the azure web app to debug.` ...But in my case i am still developing the project inside visual studio,, so still i did not deploy it inside azure.. so is there a similar/exact replacement to what the azure service bus use to do, in enabling us to debug the RER (Provider-Hosted app) inside visual studio?

Comment: You can use ngrok instead https://www.google.com/amp/s/derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/amp/

Comment: thanks i already read this link before,, but it uses different appraoch for creating RER.. now i am following the steps mentioned here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ so can i use ngrok instead of azure service bus in my case?

Comment: Yes try ngrok instead

Comment: i ried it, but when i type the generated url such as `http://ebec8431.ngrok.io/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc` while the visual studio is running, i got `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: can you advice on my above comment?

Answer (score 1):

I've founded a little trick. We should launch VS *as an administrator*. This simple action solved the same issue as described in the topic.